# Kohana 3 ORM Table Naming

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

My question is about the conventions around a multi-worded MySQL table name e.g. "comments_flags," which is not a pivot table.

- What is the correct database table name for "comments_flags"?
- What would the corresponding model name be?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no different then for single word cases.

> What is the correct database table name for "comments_flags"?

comments_flags

> What would the corresponding model name be?

Model_Comments_Flag

> What should be the path to the model?

```
application/classes/model/comments/flag.php
```

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, with Kohana, a model is only seen as a pivot table if it is used from another model with the 'through' setting? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually for pivot table you don't have to write the model at all! Just specify the 'through' setting in both models that form the pivot.